# Guessing a number between 1 ~ 100

Tags: probability, game-theory

There is a target number between [1, 100]. Player A and Player B guess a number. Who ever has a closer distance to the target, that player win.

Eg. A guesses 70, B guesses 80, but the target is 72. So A wins.

What would be the optimal strategy for player A and B? If you are player A, do you want to go first or second?

---

Attempt:

Assume uniform distribution, The expected value of [1,100] = 50.5

Thus, player A should pick 50. After that, player B should pick 51.

If player B picks 51, then player A have a chance of winning = 50% (because numbers from 1 ~ 50 will be closer to player A). And player B have also have a chance of wining = 50%.

Comment: That is the correct optimal strategy.  It still remains to be *proven* that it is the optimal strategy.  What do you know about game theory and nash equilibria?  (*Technically, both players will want to go second, in case their opponent has not figured out the strategy, but if we assume that both players are intelligent and are aware of their opponent's intelligence, they realize it is a moot point*)

Comment: Does the second player get to know what the first place picks? I'm assuming this as from your statement that a player may go first or second. If they don't know what the other guesses that negates the point of being first or second.

Comment: @IanMiller, Yes, the second player gets to know what the first player picks

Comment: @JMoravitz, I don't know about the game theory and nash equillibria

Comment: Assuming the 'target number' is chosen at random: if the first player picks 70, then I'll guess 69.

Comment: You should provide specific assumptions about the distribution of the target number and the available moves. Are target numbers integers? Can players guess a real numbers? Can Player 2 guess the same number as Player 1?

Comment: Generally speaking, the best move for Player 1 to guess a value as close to the median as possible.

Comment: @mlc, median you mean in terms of probabilty right?

Comment: @mlc, the assumption is that only integer number (target and player's guess), and no two player can guess a same number. Assume uniform distribution